# Concat object to array if object does not exits

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

`mycolumn` is a jsonb type with a default value of an empty array.

I would like to update this array if the new value is not already present.

select query:

```
SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE id = 1;
```

returns: `[]`

update query:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = mycolumn || '[{"foo":"bar"}]' WHERE id = 1;
```

Select returns: `[{"foo":"bar"}]`

If the update query is run more than once, it will append the value to the array.

Run update again, select returns `[{"foo":"bar"},{"foo":"bar"}]`, etc.

Is there an idempotent method of updating the `mycolumn` array value?

Comment: What should happen if `mycolumn` already holds multiple array elements? Should a solution replace in all elements, just in the first, or just in the first of which already holds such a key?

Comment: @pozs In my use case, the array should only have unique objects and no duplicates. Should an update occur where a new object to insert exits in the array, then nothing should happen. To put it another way, the update should be additive because the object does not exist in the array, else noop.

Comment: so, it won't "update" (modify) existing objects in the array in any possible case? would you like to find a way to either add the object, if it doesn't exists then do nothing? What should happen, if the object "partially" exists? I.e. the original value: `[{"a":"b","c":"d"},{"e":"f"}]` and you want to "insert" f.ex. `{"a":"b"}`? -- or 
back and forth: `[{"a":"b"},{"e":"f"}]` and `{"a":"b","c":"d"}`?

Comment: For my case, partially existing means the objects are not identical and the new object should be appended to the array. Your example should append `{"a":"b"}` to the existing array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "partial" containment is off the table, then the containment operators (`<@` and `@>`) are no good for you. You'll need to check each element for equality:

```
with append(a) as (
  values (jsonb '{"foo":"bar"}')
)
update mytable
set    mycolumn = mycolumn || a
from   append
where  id = 1
and    not exists(
  select 1
  from   jsonb_array_elements(mycolumn) e
  where  e = a
)
```

*Note*: you can avoid the CTE (the `WITH` clause) if you are willing to repeat the JSON object you want to "insert".

http://rextester.com/IAHE54266

Answer (score 4):

Use `<@` or `@>` operator to check is value already exists in the array:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mycolumn = mycolumn || '[{"foo":"bar"}]'
WHERE id = 1 AND NOT '[{"foo":"bar"}]'::jsonb <@ mycolumn;
```

Note that it works properly only for single value. For example:

```
select '[{"foo":"bar"},{"foo":"baz"}]'::jsonb <@ '[{"foo":"bar"},{"win":"amp"}]'::jsonb;
```

is FALSE even it have common `{"foo":"bar"}` object. In such cases you shoul to decompose the array and compose it again using DISTINCT:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mycolumn = (
  SELECT jsonb_agg(DISTINCT j) 
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(mycolumn || '[{"foo":"bar"},{"win":"amp"}]') AS j);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you've chosen the wrong jsonb data structure. It sounds like you used an array of objects while you should have used a single object, which is like a dictionary.

Try this:

```
create table mytable (id serial primary key, mycolumn jsonb not null default '{}');
insert into mytable values (default);
update mytable set mycolumn = mycolumn || '{"foo":"bar"}'::jsonb;
update mytable set mycolumn = mycolumn || '{"foo":"baz"}'::jsonb;
update mytable set mycolumn = mycolumn || '{"stack":"overflow"}'::jsonb;
select * from mytable;
 id |              mycolumn               
----+-------------------------------------
  1 | {"foo": "baz", "stack": "overflow"}
```

Comment: The column type should be an array of objects. An object with many key value pairs will not work.